# Data table in JavaScript and dc-js

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am new using `Javascript`, `dc.js` and `crossfilter`. So far, my dashboard is responding when I click to select specified district or ward. I also respond to the count of total data selected but it's not showing me the ones selected in a datable (VisTable)...

What I am doing wrong here?

```
<div id="Districtname">
  <strong>District Name</strong>
  <span class="reset" style="display: none;">Selected: <span class="filter">    
  </span></span>
  <a class="reset" href="
  javascript:districtnamechart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display:
     none;">reset</a>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>



</div>
<div id="wardname">
  <strong>Ward Name</strong>
  <span class="reset" style="display: none;">Selected: <span class="filter">    
  </span></span>
  <a class="reset" href="
  javascript:wardnamechart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display:
     none;">reset</a>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>

 <div>
    <div class="dc-data-count">
        <span class="filter-count"></span> selected out of <span class="total-count"></span> records | <a
            href="javascript:dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();">Reset All</a>
</div>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover dc-data-table">
</table>



<script src="crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="d3.js"></script>
<script src="dc.js"></script>

<script>

    var districtnamechart = dc.rowChart("#Districtname"),
      wardnamechart = dc.rowChart("#wardname"),
      visCount = dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count"),
      visTable = dc.dataTable(".dc-data-table");



    d3.csv("universe_test.csv", function (err,data) {

           //,kmist,city,district,ward,Lat,Long
           //0,KTMPVN15707,Ho Chi Minh,Can Gio,Can Thanh,10.41525,106.97254
           //1,KTMPVN15706,Ho Chi Minh,Can Gio,Can Thanh,10.41392,106.97056


        if (err) throw err; 

        var ndx = crossfilter(data);
        var all = ndx.groupAll();

        var districtDIM = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d["district"]; })
          ;
        var wardDIM = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d["ward"]; 
          });

        var districtgroup = districtDIM.group();
        var wardgroup = wardDIM.group();

        districtnamechart
            .height(800)
            .dimension(districtDIM)
            .group(districtgroup)
            .elasticX(true);

        wardnamechart
            .height(800)
            .dimension(wardDIM)
            .group(wardgroup)
            .elasticX(true)
            .data(function (group) { return group.top(20); });


        visCount
        .dimension(ndx)
        .group(all);

        visTable
        .dimension(ndx)
        .group(all)
        .columns([
            "district"
            "ward"
            ]);


        dc.renderAll();

    });  
</script>
```

My error code :

```
Uncaught TypeError: _chart.dimension(...).bottom is not a function
    at nestEntries (dc.js:6615)
    at renderGroups (dc.js:6587)
    at Object._chart._doRender (dc.js:6501)
    at Object._chart.render (dc.js:1654)
    at Object.dc.renderAll (dc.js:251)
    at (index):109
    at Object.<anonymous> (d3.js:1996)
    at Object.event (d3.js:504)
    at XMLHttpRequest.respond (d3.js:1949)
```

Comment: Refer this issue please https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1115

Comment: @insomniac It looks like an issue when agregating the data. Im simply tring to visualize the data selected...

Comment: @insomniac is close. A `dc.dataTable` normally takes a crossfilter dimension for its dimension property, and a *function* for its group property (totally inconsistent and weird but them's the facts). You are attempting to pass a crossfilter object and a groupAll object. Please try passing an actual dimension and a grouping function - you should get better results!

Comment: @Gordon I've try that and still not working  Ive tried   visTable
       .dimension(districtDIM)
   .group(wardDIM);. Basically I would like a scrolling table which i can see all my elements selected. I dont want to group them. Is there simple way to show that data table?

Comment: Hello, as I said you need to pass a function for the `group` parameter. I bet you are getting a new error which tells you this. Then you can call [.showGroups(false)](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html#showGroups) to turn off the display of groups. The scrolling is a CSS thing, search for examples of `overflow-y: auto`

Comment: Forgot to mention, the function could simply be `x => x`